# Expository treatment of Schubert Cells Paper

Tags: reference-request, schubert-varieties, exposition

I was wondering about the paper by Bernstein, Gel'fand, and Gel'fand on [Schubert Cells](http://iopscience.iop.org/0036-0279/28/3/R01;jsessionid=E4D2896AE55597FA4F4F63297F63FBC6.c3). This paper is fairly old(and often cited) so I figured someone must have represented this material. In particular, I was wondering if this was treated in an expository paper. More generally, I was wondering if there was a paper that explained the usefulness of the Schubert Calculus for representation theory, and even better one that talked about how Schubert Calculus came into the picture for BBD, again hopefully in an expository way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lecture Notes in Mathematics number 1689, "Schubert Varieties and Degeneracy Loci" by Fulton and Pragacz seems to be exactly what you're looking for. I think chapter 6 is particularly relevant.

Comment: thanks! From a first glance this appears to be exactly what I was looking for. 

Answer (score 2):

You might enjoy [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306414) article by Harry Tamvakis.

Comment: thank you, this looks interesting. I will give it a look. 

Comment: turns out I had already found this a couple weeks ago and printed it! Thanks though!